# aws session manager to instances without public IP or EIP

Tags: aws

I am trying to set up session manager to connect to my instances, and I am facing an issue with instances that do not have public IP or EIP.

What I have done is created a role and attach the  **AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore** Policy.

When I launch an instance (Amazon 2 or Ubuntu) with public IP or EIP everything is ok, as soon as I attach the role it works.

But when I do not have Public IP or EIP I am not able to connect.

Any idea? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

The instances must be able to connect to SSM service endpoint. If they don’t have a Public IP then they must be in a subnet with  default route through a NAT gateway. Otherwise they can’t talk to the internet and in turn can’t connect to the SSM service

See [**NAT Gateway for EC2 instances**](https://serverfault.com/questions/934948/nat-gateway-for-ec2-instances/934950#934950) for more details.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, yes indeed it helps.
I was using public subnet with IGW, shouldn't that work as well since my instances they do have internet access , but via the IGW instead.

Comment: Hi Adagio! If you have a comment, please use the "add a comment" button rather than posting it as an answer. Thanks!